# Freezes while frontend development

Tags: application-development, freeze, memory-usage, visual-studio-code, 21.04

I use **`Ubuntu 21.04`**. I'm working on an angular application using **`Visual Studio Code`** as my editor and **`Google Chrome`** for testing on an ASUS VivoBook s15(i7-8thgen, 8gigram, 250ssd). I use `ng serve...` then make changes and check the changes in the browser etc... My problem is that it always **freezes**.

The first freeze after restart takes a while but after the first freeze, it keeps freezing quite often. I can recover using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> but I have to do it very often and things keep getting more and more sluggish. I tried reinstalling the while system still the same issue. I think it's a memory issue.

I was googling the problem tried a few things like setting memory swap to take place only when memory fully used but nothing helped. I thought of switching to Windows or Mac at this point but I really don't want to, I love Ubuntu, but this development is just very difficult.

Please any general settings that I can do on a fresh Ubuntu install to avoid getting issues like these?

Answer (score 0):

I faced nearly the same issue with 21.04 [vscode, node, react-native, watchman].
I would suggest to downgrade to 20.10 or 20.04 which I probably do too. I can't recall such memory drain since 19.04.
My config has 32G of ram which get exhausted very quick :(

Comment: I did that. Also I was on 8gb ram, upgraded to 16gb now it's working but it's bearly enough but it's better. Any case I think I should increase the swp space to avoid complete freeze, which is only set to 2gb. So the solution I guess get more ram and increase swp space.